# Headless on RPi - checking boot screen messages for jackd

Tags: boot, audio

I'm trying to run an RPi autonomously and have a script which is intended to start jackd and then Supercollider. The script works from the command line if I ssh into the RPi, but not otherwise. To try and work out what is failing I'd like to see the jackd and Supercollider boot screen messages. Any ideas how to do this ? Or make the script work ?

I am starting Jackd and sclang from a script :

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `dbus-launch --auto-syntax`
sleep 2
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_PID DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
sleep 2
export DISPLAY=:0.0
sleep 2
usr/local/bin/jackd -p32 -dalsa -dhw:0,0 -p1024 -n3 -s -r44100 &
sleep 10
sclang
```

This works if I ssh into the RPi :

```
ssh -X pi@192.168.2.3
```

and then call the script, but not if I reboot the RPi without being connected. I know the script is being called (from crontab) as I have had the script send messages to a text file.

I've tried various permutations of the script, the latest being :

```
#!/bin/bash
usr/local/bin/jackd -p32 -dalsa -dhw:0,0 -p1024 -n3 -s -r44100 &
sleep 10
sclang
```

Answer (score 0):

First question before we can proceed further:

How do you actually start jackd and or supercollider?

If they have an init script, you can always check /var/log/daemon.log

Comment: more information added to the original question above